# Can Common Protractor Test Scenarios be Implemented Once?

Tags: angularjs, protractor, angularjs-e2e

Is there a way to implement an protractor test case, say the login scenario, once rather than for every test that needs a user to be logged in?  I know using page objects make it easier to test login, but it would be nice to just to log a person in and then run all my tests then log the user out once then do it for every 'it' test block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// if you want to login and logout before every 'it' statement:    
var loginPage = require('./login.js');

describe('this test spec', function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
        loginPage.login();
    });
    afterEach(function() {
        loginPage.logout();
    });
    it('should log in and out with the first test', function() {
        expect(loginPage.isLoggedIn()).toBe(true);
    });
    it('should log in and out with the second test', function() {
        expect(loginPage.isLoggedIn()).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

OR

```
// if you want to login before every 'spec' file and stay logged in:
// in protractor.conf.js
// in exports.config

onPrepare: function() {
    var blahBlah = require('./login.js');
    blahBlah.login();
}

describe('this test spec', function() {
    it('should log in before the first test', function() {
        expect(loginPage.isLoggedIn()).toBe(true);
    });
    it('and stay logged in for the second test', function() {
        expect(loginPage.isLoggedIn()).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

Comment: onPrepare looks like is the answer.  I also found this example from protractor faq page: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/spec/withLoginConf.js